# Maven - What is the windows equivalent of .file to pass a file containing properties from the command line

Tags: maven

Newby Maven question...

I am trying to run some tests in a Java Test Automation Framework.

This commmand works fine in linux:

```
mvn test -Denv.file=src/test/resources/env/.env
```

However, when I try to run it in Windows I get this error:

Unknown lifecycle phase ".file=src/test/resources/env/.env". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format

I am presuming that -Denv.file works on Linux but you need a different command on Windows?

I've tried googling but can't find anything.

Comment: I suppose you adding a space somewhere. This should be given: `mvn test -Denv.file=src/test/resources/env/.env`. but you might give this: `mvn test -Denv .file=src/test/resources/env/.env`.

Comment: Apart from that why do you need this kind of property to run your test? Which test automation framework do you use?